# Choose the false statement of given matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let A be a square matrix such that $A^{3} =  0 $, but $A^{2} \neq 0$. Then which of
the following statements is not necessarily true?

(A) $A\neq  A^{2} $

(B) Eigenvalues of $ A^{2} $ are all zero

(C) $\text{rank}(A) > \text{rank}(A^{2})$

(D) $\text{rank}(A) > \text{trace}(A)$

My attempt : [image]

My correct answer is option 2), but I'm doubting little bits... is my answer is correct or incorrect pliz verified and tell me the solution, I would be more thankful.

Answer (score 1):

Your computation of the eigenvalues of $A^2$ with the given example is wrong.

Note that if $v$ is a non-zero eigenvector corresponding to a eigenvalue $\lambda$ we have  $Av=\lambda v$ and
$$A^nv= A^{n-1} (Av)= A^{n-1}(\lambda v)=\dots= \lambda^nv.$$ 
What may we conclude?

P.S. As regards option C, note that $\text{rank}(A^n)\geq \text{rank}(A^{n+1})$. Moreover if $\text{rank}(A^{n})=\text{rank}(A^{n+1})$, then $\text{rank}(A^{n})=\text{rank}(A^{n+k})$ for all $k\geq 0$. This implies that in our case also option C is true.

Comment: @ Robert Z  why u delete that  counter example matrix...as i have take ur counter example matrix,,,all option a, b , c, and  are all satisfied,,,,,,,but im confuse which option is false

Comment: @lomberlego That example was useless for your question. It remains  to show if there is a counterexample for option C (see also ploosu2's answer).

Comment: @lomberlego I think that also option C is true. They are all true! Could you please check your statement?

Comment: @ RObert Z ,,then according to  question,,which option is not necssarily true.?.as  i have read both of  ur answer and ploosu2.. answer..i did n't found any option  that is not necessarily true,,all are option a,b ,c,and d are nceesarily true,,,

Comment: @lomberlego Yes, they are all true. May I know where this exercise come from? Did you write the statement correctly?

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiGiK6nq5jXAhVBrI8KHZf_BLAQFggoMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.isical.ac.in%2F~admission%2F&usg=AOvVaw23L-jKOOXU2RJCMJ2nLwKT...........      M. Maths question -year 2016  question no. 28

Comment: @lomberlego  I see. It seems that in this case all the options are necessarily true.

Comment: @ Robert Z im also thinking that  this  question may be.. wrong  or may be some typing mistakes ?

Comment: @lomberlego Yes, it could be a typo.

Answer (score 1):

$A\neq A^2$ must be true, otherwise $A^3 = A^2A = AA = A^2 \neq 0$.

The eigenvalues of $A^k$ are the eigenvalues of $A$ raised the the $k$th power, so for $A^3$ to be zero, the eigenvalues of $A$ must all be zero. Hence also the eigenvalues of $A^2$ are all zero and B must be true.

D must also be true. Trace is the sum of the eigenvalues, and since they are all zero (see the argument before), $\text{trace}(A) = 0$. The rank of $A$ must be positive since $A\neq 0$.

Only thing left is C. But can it be false either?

[EDIT]:
C must also be true: Of course $\text{rank}(A) \geq \text{rank}(A^2)$, since when you think $A$ as a linear mapping, the image of $A^2$ is a subset of the image of $A$. If $\text{rank}(A) = \text{rank}(A^2)$ this would mean that the images are equal. Hence they will be equal from the power $2$ onward and that means $\text{rank}(A^3) = \text{rank}(A^2) > 0$. But $A^3=0$, a contradiction.

(By the way, in your example you are mistaken about the rank of $A$. It can't be $3$ since otherwise $A$ would be invertible and its power would never be the zero matrix. Also the eigenvalues must be all zero.)

Comment: thanks a lots @ ploosu2,,that  mean rank A = rank of $A^{2} $  so option C is false,,Am i right ?

Comment: @lomberlego No, see the edits. C is also always true. I guess it's a trick question, then.